# Renaming variant column

Tags: bash, grep, cat, genome

I have a large file with rsIDs in the 2nd field.

Some variants are in this format: chr1-97981343:rs55886062-AT

Using bash commands, how can I replace these identifiers to just print the rsID (e.g. rs55886062)?

Toy data set:

```
1   rs3918290   110 97915614    A   G
1   chr1-97981343:rs55886062-AT 110 97981343    A   T
1   rs72549303  110 97915622    C   A
1   rs17376848  110 97915624    G   A
1   rs59086055  110 97915746    A   G
```

The desired output:

```
1   rs3918290   110 97915614    A   G
1   rs55886062  110 97981343    A   T
1   rs72549303  110 97915622    C   A
1   rs17376848  110 97915624    G   A
1   rs59086055  110 97915746    A   G
```

Answer (score 2):

If the variant format is always structured with `:` and `-`, and if you don't mind tweaking the whitespace of the file, you can do:

```
awk 'split($2, a, ":") && a[2]{ split(a[2], b, "-"); $2 = b[1] }{$1 = $1}1' input
```

Answer (score 2):

Some more samples would help to construct a regexp pattern. Here's one possible solution:

```bash
$ sed -E 's/\<chr[0-9]+-[0-9]+:(rs[0-9]+)-[A-Z]+/\1/' ip.txt
1   rs3918290   110 97915614    A   G
1   rs55886062 110 97981343    A   T
1   rs72549303  110 97915622    C   A
1   rs17376848  110 97915624    G   A
1   rs59086055  110 97915746    A   G
```

- `\<` start of word anchor
- `chr[0-9]+-[0-9]+:` match `chr` followed by one or more digits followed by `-` followed by one or more digits followed by `:`
- `(rs[0-9]+)` capture `rs` followed by one or more digits
- `-[A-Z]+` match `-` followed by one or more uppercase characters

Answer (score 0):

Following `sed` command may help

```
sed -E 's/[^[:blank:]]*(rs[0-9]+)[^[:blank:]]*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Input file is called "stack" here.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

cat stack | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '+' > s1
mv s1 stack

next () {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
exit 0
}

main () {
line=$(sed -n '1p' stack)
f1=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'+' -f1)
f2=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'+' -f2)
f3=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'+' -f3)
f4=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'+' -f4)
f5=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'+' -f5)
f6=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'+' -f6)

branch1 () {
nf2=$(echo "${f2}" | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's@\-AT@@')
echo "${f1} ${nf2} ${f3} ${f4} ${f5} ${f6}" >> output
}

branch2 () {
echo "${f1} ${f2} ${f3} ${f4} ${f5} ${f6}" >> output
}

[[ -n $(echo "${line}" | grep ":") ]] && branch1
[[ -z $(echo "${line}" | grep ":") ]] && branch2

sed -i '1d' stack
next
}

next
```

If it is within your power, within your organisation, you are diplomatically encouraged to designate a non-whitespace character as a field seperator, because it greatly simplifies processing.  My own preference is `+`, but I believe `,` is customary.

If it is not, I apologise in advance.